# Converting AggregationOutput to JsonObject

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework, json

I have a program which runs mongodb query using JAVA driver.I am storing the result into AggregationOutput. I want to convert the reult into JsonObject and pass it to other funtion.

This is my code:

```
public class JavaAggregation {

public static JsonObject ja() throws UnknownHostException{
Mongo mongo = new Mongo("localhost", 27017);
DB db = mongo.getDB("mydb");

DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("tq");

final List<DBObject> pipeline = new ArrayList<>();

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

final BasicDBObject matchObj = new BasicDBObject();

String timePeriod = "today";

switch(timePeriod){
case "today" :

int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);  
String dayS = Integer.toString(day);
matchObj.put("$match", new BasicDBObject(
        "dayofyear", dayS));
    pipeline.add(matchObj);
break; 


case "week" :
int dayW = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR); 
int dayLW = dayW - 7;
String daySW = Integer.toString(dayW);
String daySLW = Integer.toString(dayLW);
matchObj.put("$match", new BasicDBObject("dayofyear",
           new BasicDBObject("$gte", daySLW).append("$lte", daySW) ));
    pipeline.add(matchObj);
break; 

 case "month" :
int dayM = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR); 
int dayLM = dayM - 30;
String daySM = Integer.toString(dayM);
String daySLM = Integer.toString(dayLM);
matchObj.put("$match", new BasicDBObject("dayofyear",
           new BasicDBObject("$gt", daySLM).append("$lte", daySM) ));
    pipeline.add(matchObj);
    break; 

default :
System.out.println("Invalid Entry");
} 
DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", new BasicDBObject("_id", "$term")
.append("totalcount", new BasicDBObject("$sum", "$count")));
pipeline.add(group);


DBObject sort1 = null;
BasicDBObject sortByCount = null;
sortByCount = new BasicDBObject( "totalcount", -1 );
sort1 = new BasicDBObject( "$sort", sortByCount);
pipeline.add(sort1);

AggregationOutput output = coll.aggregate(pipeline);

for (DBObject res : output.results()) {
    System.out.println(res);
}
}
}
```

Output:

```
{ "_id" : "aero" , "totalcount" : 26}
{ "_id" : "aero storm tour" , "totalcount" : 3}
```

I want to convert the output Into JsonObject and return it to other function.How to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Java JSON jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavajsonjar.htm) or [gson jar](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/detail?name=google-gson-2.2.4-release.zip&), here I used `Java JSON Jar`. Changed for loop as below :

```
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    for (DBObject res : output.results()) {
        System.out.println(res);
        JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject();
        jsonobj.put("_id", res.get("_id"));
        jsonobj.put("totalcount", res.get("totalcount"));
        jsonArray.put(jsonobj);
    }
    System.out.println(jsonArray);
```

Comment: It might be better to `.parse()` the string output of DBObject rather than manually set every key here.

Comment: @BlakesSeven : Can you please give an example explaining it ?

Comment: @BlakesSeven `output.results()` return `iterable<DBObject>` is number of documents return by query. It's not return `String` and in java we not assign `loop`  data to any variable so `.parse()` also not possible, so iterate over data and push data into `JSONArray`

Comment: I am not saying `.parse()` the iterable object but parse each DBOBject output as string. Yes that is possible and a lot cleaner that accessing each key of the object and putting them into the JSONObject indvidually.

Comment: @BlakesSeven you are right is possible to put like this  `jsonArray.put(res);`  but problem here if `_id` field is mongo generated `_id` then it returns all `_id` related data like `date,currentCounter,generatedMachineIdentifier...` so either in `aggregation project add _id :0` or put `_id` as user defined value in this case `"_id" : "aero"`

Comment: I am doing it like this.It works perfectly.Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray(); for (DBObject res : output.results()) { `JsonParser parser=new JsonParser();`  `Object obj = parser.parse(res.toString());`  jsonArray.add((JsonElement) obj); }